# Enlarge graphic axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pgfplots

I have a function ploted with pgfplots:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    xlabel=$X$,
    ylabel=$Y$,
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    grid,
    grid style={green},
    major tick style={draw=black, thick},
    xticklabels={,,},
    yticklabels={,,},
    xmin=-5,
    xmax=5,
    ymin=-5,
    ymax=5,
    xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
    ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
    axis line style={thick},
    samples=250,
    unit vector ratio*=1 1,
    tick label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    every axis label = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    legend style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    ]

    \addplot [ultra thick, red]{42/27 *((x*x*x)/3 - (x*x)/2 - 2*x) +59/27} node [pos=0.75,left,black,{font=\sansmath\sffamily}] {$f(x)$};

    \draw[very thick, blue] (axis cs: -2.5,4)--(axis cs: 0.5,4);
    \draw[very thick, blue] (axis cs: 3.5,-3)--(axis cs: 0.5,-3);
    \node[above] at (axis cs: -1,4) {\sffamily\textit P};
    \node[below] at (axis cs: 2,-3) {\sffamily\textit Q};

\end{axis};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The graphic generated by that code is the first one.
The second one is the one that I want to achieve.

Then, I want to do severals changes that can be seen in both graphics:

- Enlarge axis to put "X" and "Y" outside the grid, *without* putting a tick in `x = −6` and `y = −6`. (I mean, I want to get the axis of the second figure, but not to finish the X axis in the left part by: "`|---`", but yes by "`---`"... and the same to the Y axis).
- Only put labels in `x = 1` and in `y = 1`.
- (If it's possible) Remove of the `font=\sansmath\sffamily` of the `f(x)` node and include it in the axis options to affect to all nodes.
- (If it's possible). Isn't there any other method to indicate tangent lines in points like P or Q, instead of doing it manually in TikZ as I did?

[image: Graphics]

Comment: Related to your first question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69180/extend-axis-outside-boxed-area-in-pgfplots/70351#70351

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You could use `axis line style={shorten > = -0.5cm, shorten < = -0.5cm}` to extend the axis lines. Note that this doesn't increase the bounding box, so you might have to adjust this manually.
2. You can use `extra x ticks={1},
   extra x tick label=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}` to print the tick labels.
3. You can put `font=\sansmath\sffamily` in the `axis` options to apply it to all text in the axis.
4. You should probably ask a separate question for this.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    xlabel=$X$,
    ylabel=$Y$,
    axis x line=center, xlabel style={anchor=south west},
    axis y line=center, ylabel style={anchor=south west},
    grid,
    grid style={green},
    major tick style={draw=black, thick},
    xmin=-5,
    xmax=5,
    ymin=-5,
    ymax=5,
    xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
    xticklabels={},
    extra x ticks={1},
    extra x tick label=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick},
    ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
    yticklabels={},
    extra y ticks={1},
    extra y tick labels=1,
    axis line style={thick, shorten > = -0.5cm, shorten < = -0.5cm},
    samples=50,
    unit vector ratio*=1 1,
    font=\sansmath\sffamily,
    ]

    \addplot [ultra thick, red, smooth]{42/27 *((x*x*x)/3 - (x*x)/2 - 2*x) +59/27} node [pos=0.75,left,black] {$f(x)$};

    \draw[very thick, blue] (axis cs: -2.5,4)--(axis cs: 0.5,4);
    \draw[very thick, blue] (axis cs: 3.5,-3)--(axis cs: 0.5,-3);
    \node[above] at (axis cs: -1,4) {$P$};
    \node[below] at (axis cs: 2,-3) {$Q$};
\end{axis};

\path (current axis.south west) +(-0.5cm,-0.5cm) (current axis.north east) +(0.5cm,0.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```